# Cannot Connect Via RDP

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-terminal-services, netstat

I cannot connect via RDP to a win2003 server.  Terminal services say that they're started, but a netstat shows nothing to do with port 3389.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the -a switch with Netstat?  If not, it's only showing you active connections (vs. all listening).  Are you testing RDP from the same subnet?

Comment: I'm using the -an switch.  I'm also testing on the same subnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incoming RDC isn't enabled by default. You need to ensure that "enable remote desktop on this computer" is checked on the computer's properties dialogue. You also need to ensure that the firewall exception is turned on too (enabling the checkbox will add this if it is not present, but I don't think it selects it by default).

Comment: Is there a possibility for any reasons(besides user intervention) for the "enable remote desktop on this computer" to be unchecked after a server restart?

Comment: @sc_ray: I've never seen that happen. Installing or changing 3rd party firewall or firewall management software might cause disruption, as may errant patches from Windows Update (but that will be something that is heavily tested before updates are released: it would be *very* embarrassing if they released an update that accidentally removed access to everyones remote servers!